# Extracting Schema Information from XML to a data.frame

Tags: r, xml

I am attempting to parse some XML result sets (generated from SQL queries passed through a SOAP API) that contain both schema information and data.

I've managed to get the data using the `XML` package, but I'm struggling to extract the schema information to the `R` environment.

#### Sample XML and Row Extraction

```
library(magrittr)
library(XML)

## Example XML to parse
file <- '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rowset xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:saw-sql="urn:saw-sql" targetNamespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset">
    <xsd:complexType name="Row">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Column0" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:displayFormula="Description"/>
        <xsd:element name="Column1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="numeric" saw-sql:displayFormula="Number"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
  <Row>
    <Column0>foo</Column0>
    <Column1>1.2</Column1>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Column0>bar</Column0>
    <Column1>2.3</Column1>
  </Row>
</rowset>
'
## Extract the rows    
file %>% 
  XML::xmlParse() %>% 
  XML::xmlRoot() %>%
  XML::xmlElementsByTagName(.,"Row",TRUE) %>% 
  xmlToDataFrame() -> DF

print(DF)
```

returns the following

```
  Column0 Column1
1     foo     1.2
2     bar     2.3
```

#### Attempted Schema Extraction

Ideally, I would like to extract a second data frame with the column information so that I can use that to properly format my result set. However, the furthest I've been able to get is a list of elements. From what I understand, these are stored as external pointers, and I've struggled to get these pulled back into the R environment.

```
file %>% 
  XML::xmlParse() %>% 
  XML::xmlRoot() %>%
  XML::xmlElementsByTagName(.,"element",TRUE)
```

which yields

```
$schema.complexType.sequence.element
<xsd:element name="Column0" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="varchar" saw-sql:displayFormula="Description"/> 

$schema.complexType.sequence.element
<xsd:element name="Column1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" saw-sql:type="numeric" saw-sql:displayFormula="Number"/>
```

#### Desired Output

What I would really shooting for is something like the following:

```
     name       type minOccurs maxOccurs saw.sql.type saw.sql.displayFormula
1 Column0 xsd:string         0         1      varchar            Description
2 Column1 xsd:string         0         1      numeric                 Number
```

*(output example generation)*

```
data.frame(name = c("Column0","Column1"),
           type = "xsd:string",
           minOccurs = "0",
           maxOccurs="1",
           `saw-sql:type`= c("varchar","numeric"),
           `saw-sql:displayFormula` = c("Description","Number"))
```

Would be grateful for any pointers on what I'm missing here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get_stuff <- function(y, stuff) { unlist(lapply(y, function(x) x[[stuff]])) }

xml_list <- xmlToList(file)[["schema"]][["complexType"]][["sequence"]]

DF <- data.frame(name = get_stuff(xml_list, "name"),
                 type = get_stuff(xml_list, "type"),
                 minOccurs = get_stuff(xml_list, "minOccurs"),
                 maxOccurs = get_stuff(xml_list, "maxOccurs"),
                 saw_sql_type = get_stuff(xml_list, "type"),
                 saw_sql_displayFormula = get_stuff(xml_list, "displayFormula"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind, xmlToList(file)$schema$complexType$sequence), row.names=NULL)
     name       type minOccurs maxOccurs  type.1 displayFormula
1 Column0 xsd:string         0         1 varchar    Description
2 Column1 xsd:string         0         1 numeric         Number
```